# Connecting to secure WebDAV makes Nautilus hang up

Tags: nautilus, webdav

I just received a box.com account from my school and, since Box Sync does not exist for Linux, I instead tried using the WebDAV service box.com offers.

I tried the Nautilus:`File`->`Connect to Server...` way. The connection works; I can access the files on the Box server.

However, from the moment I connect to the server, Nautilus takes ages to process any user input, both in and out of the WebDAV connection. As soon as I disconnect from the WebDAV server, it's working again.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now use the davfs2 aproach, as shown [here](http://xmodulo.com/2013/02/how-to-mount-box-com-cloud-storage-on-linux.html). Now I have to mount/unmount the WebDAV
folder via a terminal, but everything works.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to `box.com` using `nautilus` connect to server feature you must install `davf2s` in `synaptic` manager.

Now open nautilus and click on Connect to Server. When window opens, type on the server address line the following:

```
davs://dav.box.com/dav
```

A dialog window will open to request from you your account id and your password to connect.